# How to display the image of each video frame in wxpython

Tags: wxpython

I want to display each image from video frame on wxpython, for example, in a panel block. Like when I use imshow in opencv, but now I can control the output in my own window.
Is there any ways to do this? Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you need to be able to access every video frame. For example with OpenCV you can loop through the VideoCapture:

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture("filename.mpeg")
while 1:
    (grabbed, frame) = cam.read()
    if grabbed:
        frame
        # frame is a numpy array containing the image from the video
```

Now you have got the frame, which you can display for example with cv2.imshow. With wxpython you need to convert this bitmap to something wxpython can display, which is a wx.Bitmap. So you can do:

```
bitmap = wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(width, height, frame)
```

If you do not know how to display a wx.Bitmap, you better start with a wxPython docs and demos.